# PHP incorrectly displaying Date

Tags: php, oracle, datetime

As part of a recent upgrade to Apache2.2/PHP 5.5.20 (from Apache 1.3/PHP 5.3) I found the following problem:

Whenever PHP attempts to retrieve a Date data type from Oracle, the result is parsed as a string and the YYYY-MM-DD part of it is removed from it:

```
$tempQuery = "SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL";
$tempStatement = oci_parse($this->conn, $tempQuery);
$tempSuccess = oci_execute($tempStatement);
oci_fetch_all($tempStatement, $tempData);
echo "<h3>var_dump(\$tempData) :" . var_dump($tempData)  . "</h3>";
```

var_dump($tempData)

We get:

```
array(1) { 
  ["SYSDATE"]=> array(1) { 
    [0]=> string(8) "20:02:20" 
  } 
}
```

We are using PHP 5.5.20, Apache 2.2, Oracle Server 11i, Oracle Client 9, SUSE Linux 11 SP2

I realize the best way to fix this would be to format the date in PL/SQL but this is not possible since this is a legacy functionality. Needless to say this was working fine before the upgrade.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not really good with Oracle, but had you read this? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/fuecks-dates-098686.html